# WPML admin-ajax.php call not localized after setting lang

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wpml

Calls to `__()` in an AJAX function are not translated even after I set the `lang` parameter in the AJAX URL.

It appears that Sitepress is not detecting the lang parameter properly.

I've found a workaround, but it seems cumbersome.

```
global $sitepress;
$sitepress->switch_lang($_REQUEST['lang'], true);

load_theme_textdomain( 'mytextdomain', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```